# Install vsix package both on Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 with WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX setup project that installs VSIX packages using the wix:VsixPackage element from the Vs extension.

I am trying to modify this setup project to support both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017. So I've modified the setup definition like this:

```
<Component Id="Modeling.Factory" Guid="1A5C7D5C-676E-46D9-9808-5FE79A51B8B3">
    <File
        Id="Modeling.Factory.vsix"
        Name="Primavera.Modeling.Factory.Shell3.vsix"
        Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\Bin\Primavera.Modeling.Factory.Shell3.vsix"
        Vital="yes">
        <wix:VsixPackage
            PackageId="FA9F2DC1-30A2-4C88-AFC6-3CD5A49C39CB"
            Target="Pro"
            TargetVersion="14.0"
            Permanent="no"
            Vital="yes" />
        <wix:VsixPackage
            PackageId="FA9F2DC1-30A2-4C88-AFC6-3CD5A49C39CB"
            Target="Pro"
            TargetVersion="15.0"
            Permanent="no"
            Vital="yes" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

Notice the two `Target` and `TargetVersion` settings.

The setup builds without any warning, both in VS2015 and VS2017.

When I run the setup it fails. The setup log file includes this line that identifies the problem:

```
MSI (s) (A0:3C) [11:36:57:314]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=vim2916624A52A9C02C06B731DECBEAB911,ActionType=3122,Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,Target=/q  /skuName:Pro /skuVersion:15.0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\PRIMAVERA\Elevation SDK v3.00\Temp\Primavera.Modeling.Factory.Shell3.vsix" /admin,)
CustomAction vim2916624A52A9C02C06B731DECBEAB911 returned actual error code 2003 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

So the problem is that the setup is trying to install the VSIX package to VS2017 using the VS2015 version of the VSIXnstaller.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possibly a bug in WiX?

I am using WiX v3.11.0.1507.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The changes in VS2017 require changes in VsixInstaller that are apparently not feasible without further changes in VS2017: http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5433-add-support-to-detect-and-install-vsix-packages-into-vs15/

Comment: I don't understand. According to this the issue is closed.
[Add detection property support for VS2017](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/pull/421)

Comment: You may need to modify your vsix to support 2017. Now it's version 3 (2015 is version 2), it's not about installing it's about the vsix manifest itself.. does your vsix install successfully with double click for example? https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Visual-Studio-2017-Extensions-Update

Comment: That pull request implemented detection properties, not the custom actions needed to property invoke VSIXInstaller.exe.